# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field... but I am not making a static reference

Tags: java, android

I am quite confused as how/why this could be a problem:

```
public static long someMethod
{
  long local_temp_var = PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime;    
}
```

gives error message

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field
>   PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime

The error messafe claims I am trying to make a static reference? I don't really believe I am. Yes, it is in a static/class method, but the variable is a local one.

Comment: PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime should be static

Comment: PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime should be static, it's not. Is PackageInfo a class that you made ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. the problem is that the variable `lastUpdateTime` in `PackageInfo` IS NOT static! But you are calling it as if it was.

[JavaDoc of PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#lastUpdateTime)

You have to create a new instance of `PackageInfo` aka...

`PackageInfo info = new PackageInfo();`

then you can do....

`long local_temp_var = info.lastUpdateTime; // Take note the "info" variable from above`

Comment: I must have had a brain freeze. It threw me off "Cannot make a static reference", but the error message makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access non static fields in  the `static` context.

Since the field `lastUpdateTime`  is non `static`,it is saying to make it `static` or don't use here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a static method

```
//notice the () brackets you miss in your question.
public static long someMethod() {...}
```

All references therein are considered static.

`but the variable is a local one.`

Yes, a local **instance** variable. Not *static* -- this is the cause of the error you see.

**Also,** the naming seems to be off. `PackageInfo` seems to be your local variable, but this is not how we name those: is should start with a lowercase letter.

A line in Java that reads `PackageInfo.something` sends the message: "`PackageInfo` is a class, and we access its static field named `something`". If PackageInfo is not a class, but an instance of a class, this sends a misleading message - which kills maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

If in the declaration you have mentioned:

`static long lastUpdateTime;`

Then it would fine.